# I am trying to input a string and make the first letter uppercase

Tags: c

## I don't get an error but when I do run the program it repeats what I stated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define strsize 25

void cap(char *str_cap);

 int main()
{
 
char str[strsize];
printf("enter a word with less than 25 letters\n---->");

      gets(str);
cap(str);
```

I tried using toupper  in printf but that did not work either

also I am not sure how to isolate the first letter

```
 printf("%s",str,1);

return 0;
}

void cap(char *str_cap)
{
 if(islower(str_cap)  || isupper(str_cap))
  toupper (str_cap);
  (str_cap,1);

 }
```

Comment: What is this (str_cap,1);?

Comment: It will be enough just to write *str_cap = toupper ( ( unsigned char )*str_cap);

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I do not think it is so trivial. It says "first letter" not "first char"

Comment: To expand on what Vlad said, `str_cap` is a `char *` _pointer_ but `toupper` needs _just_ a `char`. Doing `(unsigned char)` is necessary because a `char` that is (e.g.) `0x80` will be taken as a _negative_ index into the table that `toupper` uses.

Comment: @CraigEstey you do not know if this function uses any tables. The standard says that if it is not an unsigned iinteger the behaviour is not defined.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland According to the prompt "enter a word with less than 25 letters" the user may enter only ,letters.:)

Answer (score 0):

Just calling `toupper()` is not going to change the string's first character to uppercase. You have to set the first character of the string explicitly.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define strsize 25


void cap(char *str_cap);

int main()
{

    char str[strsize];
    printf("enter a word with less than 25 letters\n---->");

    fgets(str, strsize, stdin);
    
    cap(str);
    
    printf("%s",str);

    return 0;
}

void cap(char* str_cap)
{
    int length = strlen(str_cap);
    
    for(size_t i=0;i<length;i++){
        
        if(isalpha(str_cap[i])){
            
            if(islower(str_cap[i])){
                str_cap[i] = toupper(str_cap[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }    
}
```

**Input:**

```
andy baker
```

**Output:**

```
---->Andy baker
```

Comment: but it will net set the first lettter uppercase in this string `"       hello"`. The task is first letter not first char

Comment: Thanks @P__JsupportswomeninPoland, corrected the code.

Comment: 1. there is not need to call strlen. You iterate the string twice without the need.  2. `strlen` does not return `int`. point 2 ia an UB as `int` can overflow

Comment: What us UB @P__JsupportswomeninPoland ?

Comment: Undefined Behavoiur

Comment: But the max size of the string has been set to 25 right?

Comment: function `cap` does not anything aboat maxsize

Comment: The line #define strsize 25 says about it.

Comment: do you use it in that function'

Comment: fgets() will take care of the size in the main function.

Comment: if user reuses thhis function for other putposes?  Program has to be type correct. It is not disputable

Comment: Please consider moving your discussion to a chat.

Comment: discussion is pointless. You function has to use the correct types.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is good if functions return value.
2. You ask for the first letter not first char in the string which makes a difference when you want to convert `"      hello"`.
3. Check for the error conditions.

```
char *cap(char *str_cap)
{
    char *saved = str_cap;

    if(*str_cap)
    {
        while(*str_cap && !isalpha((unsigned char)*str_cap))
        {
            str_cap++;
        }
        if(*str_cap) *str_cap = toupper((unsigned char)*str_cap);
    }
    return saved;
}
```

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire read function documentation. You will learn why